# Confidence intervals on differences in choices in a GEE framework: methods and alternatives?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, mixed-model, psychometrics, random-effects-model

Say we have 5 items, and people are asked which item they like. Multiple answers are possible, but also no answer is possible. The people are categorized according to factors like gender, age, and so on. One possible approach to analyze the differences between genders, age groups and so on is making use of the [Generalized Estimating Equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_estimating_equation).

I thus construct a dataset with a binary variable indicating whether the item was liked or not, and as predictor variables I have the items, the person id, the age,... i.e. :

```
Liked   Item   Person ...
0       1      1
1       2      1
0       3      1
0       4      1
1       5      1
1       1      2
...
```

Then I apply a model with following form :
$$Liked = Item + Gender + Item*Gender + Age + Item*Age + ... $$
with Person as random factor (called id in some applications) and a logit link function.

Now I like to give confidence intervals on the conditional fractions, i.e. the confidence interval of the fractions males and females that liked a particular item, corrected for age differences and the likes. I know I could use the estimated coefficients to get the results I want, but I'm a bit lost in how to do that. I can calculate the estimated odds, but I'm not sure on the standard error (SE) on those odds based on the SE of the coefficients. I'm not sure on how to deal with the random component of the variance for example.

So:

1) Any pointers on how to calculate that SE from the SE of the coefficients?

2) Any alternatives for an approach? I've been thinking about mixed models, but a colleague directed me to GEE as more appropriate for these data. Your ideas?

---

Edit : for practical pointers, I'm using [geepack](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geepack/index.html) in R for this. I tried `effect()`, but the option `se.fit=T` is not implemented. In any case, that would give the SE for every observation, which is not what I'm interested in.

Comment: Are you working with R or Stata? Are the items locally independant (i.e. the probability of choosing any one item does not depend on response to other items)? Could you confirm that what you call "conditional fractions" are just the % of males/females that choosed a given item, adjusting for other effects in your model?

Comment: @chl : that's exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the [gee](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gee/index.html) package includes facilities for fitting GEE and `gee()` return asymptotic and robust SE. I never used the [geepack](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geepack/index.html) package. From what I saw in the online example, output seems to resemble more or less that of `gee`. To compute $100(1-\alpha)$ CIs for your main effects (e.g. gender), why not use the robust SE (in the following I will assume it is extracted from, say `summary(gee.fit)`, and stored in a variable `rob.se`)? I suppose that

```
exp(coef(gee.fit)["gender"]+c(-1,1)*rob.se*qnorm(0.975))
```

should yield 95% CIs expressed on the odds scale.

Now, in fact I rarely use GEE except when I am working with binary endpoints in longitudinal studies, because it's easy to pass or estimate a given working correlation matrix. In the case you summarize here, I would rather rely on an IRT model for dichotomous items (see the [psychometrics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Psychometrics.html) task view), or (it is quite the same in fact) a mixed-effects GLM such as the one that is proposed in the [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) package, from Doug Bates. For study like yours, as you said, subjects will be considered as random effects, and your other covariates enter the model as fixed effects; the response is the 0/1 rating on each item (which enter the model as well). Then you will get 95% CI for fixed effects, either from the SE computed as `sqrt(diag(vcov(glmm.fit)))` or as read in `summary(glmm.fit)`, or using `confint()` together with an `lmList` object. Doug Bates gave nice illustrations in the following two paper/handout:

- [Estimating the Multilevel Rasch Model: With the lme4 Package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v20/i02) (JSS, 2007 20(2))
- [Item Response Models as GLMMs](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~bates/UseR2008/WorkshopD.pdf) (from a workshop at UseR 2008)

There is also a discussion about profiling `lmer` fits (based on *profile deviance*) to investigate variability in fixed effects, but I didn't investigate that point. I think it is still in section 1.5 of Doug's [draft on mixed models](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/book/). There are a lot of discussion about computing SE and CI for GLMM as implemented in the `lme4` package (whose interface differs from the previous `nlme` package), so that you will easily find other interesting threads after googling about that.

It's not clear to me why GEE would have to be preferred in this particular case. Maybe, look at the R translation of Agresti's book by Laura Thompson, [R (and S-PLUS) Manual to Accompany Agresti's Categorical Data](https://home.comcast.net/~lthompson221/Splusdiscrete2.pdf).

---

**Update:**

I just realized that the above solution would only work if you're interested in getting a confidence interval for the gender effect alone. If it is the interaction item*gender that is of concern, you have to model it explicitly in the GLMM (my second reference on Bates's has an example on how to do it with `lmer`).

Another solution is to use an explanatory IRT model, where you explicitly acknowledge the potential effect of person covariates, like gender or age, and consider fitting them within a Rasch model, for example. This is called a Latent Regression Rasch Model, and is fully described in de Boeck and Wilson's book, *Explanatory item response models: a generalized linear and nonlinear approach* (Springer, 2004), which you can read online on [Google books](http://books.google.fr/books?id=pDeLy5L14mAC&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=latent+regression+Rasch+model&source=bl&ots=Ivct9snqQO&sig=okSBDj9TAe5gZHIcMDHOQxvAbZU&hl=fr&ei=q0yKTPlCgYDgBq-CrdoK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=latent%20regression%20Rasch%20model&f=false) (section 2.4). There are some facilities to fit this kind of model in Stata (see [there](http://www.gllamm.org/aggression.html)). In R, we can mimic such model with a mixed-effects approach; a toy example would look something like

```
lmer(response ~ 0 + Age + Sex + item + (Sex|id), data=df, binomial)
```

if I remember correctly. I'm not sure whether the [eRm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eRm/index.html) allows to easily incorporate person covariates (because we need to construct a specific design matrix), but it may be worth checking out since it provides 95% CIs too.

Comment: @Joris Maybe I will have to rework my response because it seems to me I'm not entirely answering your question; indeed, I just talked about estimating main effects of your covariates, but we can also imagine model with random slope or random intercept, or a combination thereof to derive proper estimates for each gender.

Comment: this is already more than I hoped for. I've seen a comparison between gee and glmm before, and the output differed sometimes quite substantially, hence my choice for gee. I'll check out the gee package. I suppose I could use the same approach more or less for the interaction terms, as I want the odds per item and per gender (hence the interaction terms). Or am I wrong there?

Comment: @Joris Ok, I've somewhat UPDATED my response. Under the GLMM, you can fit separate intercept and/or slope for both gender, which is not exactly the same as an interaction term (which as formulated there would also be viewed as a fixed effect). Whatever the solution you choose, you need to account for a different probability of endorsing any one of your 5 items depending on the gender of the respondent. More generally, you will useful references by just looking at *Differential Item Functioning* (DIF) on the web. I just remember that the `difR` package has interesting functionalities for this.

Comment: indeed, I want to see gender and item as a fixed effect. The research hypotheses are formulated that way. The only randomness in the whole thing is the personId. But I'll read in on the topic using your links. Thanks for the valuable help.

Comment: @Joris Other links that might be useful: http://j.mp/bzetkQ, http://j.mp/ac20UQ, http://j.mp/a1UNRb. HTH

Answer (score 2):

Following up on chl's IRT suggestion and taking a different view of the analysis (and as an answer to the original question 2).

I would see if there was dominance structure in the items, e.g. an item ordering where people that like 2 tend to like 1 but not 3 and people who like 3 tend to like 1 and 2, etc.  If so, there's a scale of some kind underneath your items and you might do better to build a measurement model of the underlying score and use those measurements as your dependent variable.  Parametric IRT models, e.g. in the R package ltm, would give you an expected score and per person standard error, if you wanted to use that as a weight in the final regression.  The mokken package can be used to see if there might be a scale in there in the first place.

The regression model decisions are then a separate but now slightly easier issue, for which existing comments provide a good overview.  Personally I'd go for a mixed effects model using lmer, but that's just my preference for more rather than less model.

Comment: +1 but Parametric IRT models make strong assumptions about unidimensionality (not obvious in the question) and local independence. Anyway, in this particular case, I would favor some kind of explanatory IRT model, like the LRRM, as explained in de Boeck & Wilson's book: person-specific covariates can be directly tested within such a model, no need to consider weights of any kind.

Comment: @chl True those *are* strong unidimensionality assumptions. That's why I suggested the Mokken procedures to see how reasonable they were.  I should have put that part first not second.  And it's quite true Joris doesn't say anything about a scale - I'm probably overgeneralizing from the survey problems I see there...  Finally, with more than a handful of respectably informative items, the explanatory IRT models I've seen (i.e covariates on theta) tend to generate the same coefficients as the regression part of a two step irt + regression procedure. Gotta ref for that someplace if you want.